# How to evaluate a variable inside Table command?

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

I'm new to Mathematica. Currently, I'm stuck with a Table command. I want to evaluate a variable named *ProbeAbsorption* inside Table command and eventually plot a 3dplot of it. All the variables except Omegamw are real

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
pi = 3.142857;
ii = Sqrt[-1] ;
ℏ = 1.05*10^-34;
c = 3.*10^8;
ϵ = 8.854187*10^-12;
NN = 1*10^43;

γ1 = 1./(1.66*10^-7);    (*1Exp[(t)^2]*)
γ = γ1/2.;
γ2 = 0.32 γ ;(*1./(1.03*10^-6);*)
γ3 = 0.32 γ ; (*1./(1.03*10^-6);*)
Ep = 2.;
ϕ = 0.;
ModΩmw = 9 γ; (*Abs[μ32 Bmw/ (2ℏ)]*)
Bmw = 1.92*10^-4;
ωp = (2. pi c)/780.2*10^-9;
ω10 = 0.;
ω1 = (2. pi c)/(775.8*10^-9);
ω21 = 0.;
ω2 = (2. pi c)/(480*10^-9);
ω31 = 0.;
detuningP = 10.3 γ ; (*ωp-ω10*);
detuning1 = 0  (*ω1-ω21*);
detuning2 = 0  (*ω2-ω31*);
μ10 = .001;
μ21 = 2.2;
μ31 = 3.;
k1 = ω1/c;
k2 = ω2/c;
Ω1 = 10 γ;   (*μ21 1./(2.ℏ);*)
Ω2 = 10 γ;     (*μ31 1./(2.ℏ);*)
Ωp = μ10 Ep/(2. ℏ);
Ωmw = ModΩmw Exp[I ϕ];
K = NN ((Abs[μ10])/(2 ℏ ϵ))^2;
G1[x] = Ω1 Sin[k1[x]];
G2[y] = Ω2 Sin[k2 [y]];


    term33[x, 
       y] = ((G1[x])^2 (detuningP + detuning2) + (G2[y])^2 (detuningP + 
            detuning1)) + 
       G1[x] G2[y] (Ωmw + Conjugate[Ωmw]);
    DD[x, y] = term11[x, y] + term22*term33[x, y];

    Susceptibility[x , y] = 
      term44[x , y]/(Abs[detuningP])^2;
    ProbeAbsorption[x, y] = Im[Susceptibility[x, y]]/K
    data = Evaluate[
      Table[ProbeAbsorption[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}], {x, -3, 
       3}, {y, -3, 3}]
    (*ListPointPlot3D[Im[data],{x,-1.1^29,1.1^29},{y,-1.1^29,1.1^29}];*)
    ListPlot3D[data] 

`Values inside the variable named *data* doesn't show the evaluated values instead, it shows`

    Sequence[{{ProbeAbsorption[-3, -3], ProbeAbsorption[-3, -2], 
       ProbeAbsorption[-3, -1], ProbeAbsorption[-3, 0], 
       ProbeAbsorption[-3, 1], ProbeAbsorption[-3, 2], 
       ProbeAbsorption[-3, 3]}, {ProbeAbsorption[-2, -3], 
       ProbeAbsorption[-2, -2], ProbeAbsorption[-2, -1], 
       ProbeAbsorption[-2, 0], ProbeAbsorption[-2, 1], 
       ProbeAbsorption[-2, 2],
```

How to get a table with Probeabsorption (dependent on values of x and y) evaluated so that I can plot it? 
Thanx in advance for any help

Comment: Use f(x_,y_):= to make your functions. Also variables detuningP,1,2 are missing and functions G1,2 are missing

Comment: Sorry for that. detuningP,1,2 and G1,2 are defined before this code. Variables are defined as
detuningP = 10.3 \[Gamma] ; (*\[Omega]p-\[Omega]10*);
detuning1 = 0  (*\[Omega]1-\[Omega]21*);
detuning2 = 0  (*\[Omega]2-\[Omega]31*);
G1[x] = \[CapitalOmega]1 Sin[k1[x]];
G2[y] = \[CapitalOmega]2 Sin[k2 [y]];
All the variables in this code are constants except Omegamw.

Comment: Can you make a simpler example of your problem?

Comment: CapitalOmega is still missing. Please edit your post and provide the missing parts in your code

Comment: @C.E. In my problem, I want a 3Dplot of the imaginary part of a variable named ProbeAbsorption which is dependent on x and y variables. Now, I want to get this variable evaluated inside a Table command i.e. it should give calculated values instead of expressions like `Sin[1*10^7[x]]`.

Comment: It is not quite clear, what do you mean by "Now, I want to get this variable evaluated inside a Table command"? Give please a minimalistic example, most simple possible, where one can easily understand what are you after. Besides the capital `K` is reserved and its use as you did is illegal. There are other syntactic errors. After having corrected them I have got a list with zeros. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: I propose to close this question as the off-topic, since the problem is based on syntactic errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed some syntactic errors. Try it:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
pi = π;    ii = I;
ℏ = 1.05*10^-34;    c = 3.*10^8;
ϵ = 8.854187*10^-12;    NN = 1*10^43;

γ1 = 1./(1.66*10^-7);(*1Exp[(t)^2]*)γ = γ1/2.;
γ2 = 0.32 γ;(*1./(1.03*10^-6);*)
γ3 = 0.32 γ;(*1./(1.03*10^-6);*)
Ep = 2.;    ϕ = 0.;
ModΩmw = 9 γ;(*Abs[μ32 Bmw/(2ℏ)]*)    Bmw = 1.92*10^-4;
ωp = (2. pi c)/780.2*10^-9;    ω10 = 0.;
ω1 = (2. pi c)/(775.8*10^-9);    ω21 = 0.;
ω2 = (2. pi c)/(480*10^-9);    ω31 = 0.;
detuningP = 10.3 γ;(*ωp-ω10*);    detuning1 = 0  (*ω1-ω21*);    detuning2 = 0  (*ω2-ω31*);
μ10 = .001;    μ21 = 2.2;    μ31 = 3.;
k1 = ω1/c;    k2 = ω2/c;
Ω1 = 10 γ;(*μ21 1./(2.ℏ);*)    Ω2 = 10 γ;(*μ31 1./(2.ℏ);*)
Ωp = μ10  Ep/(2. ℏ);    Ωmw = ModΩmw Exp[I ϕ];
k = NN ((Abs[μ10])/(2 ℏ ϵ))^2;

G1[x_] := Ω1 Sin[k1*x];
G2[y_] := Ω2 Sin[k2*y];

term1[x_, y_] := (G1[x])^2 (detuningP + detuning2 + I γ3/2.) + (G2[y])^2 (detuningP + detuning1 +  I γ2/2.) +  G1[x] G2[y] (Ωmw + Conjugate[Ωmw]);

term2 = (Abs[Ωmw])^2 - (detuningP + detuning1 +  I γ2/2.) (detuningP + detuning2 + I γ3/2.);

termA[x_, y_] := (term1[x, y])/term2;

(*ρ10=Ωp/(detuningP+I γ1/2.+termA);*)

term11[x_, y_] := 1./2. (γ3 (G1[x])^2 + γ2 (G2[y])^2) ((Abs[Ωmw])^2 - (detuningP +  detuning1) (detuningP + detuning2) + (γ2 γ3)/4.); 

term22 =  1./2. (γ2 (detuningP + detuning2) + γ3 (detuningP + detuning1));

term33[x_, y_] := ((G1[x])^2 (detuningP + detuning2) + (G2[y])^2 (detuningP + detuning1)) +  G1[x] G2[y] (Ωmw + Conjugate[Ωmw]);

DD[x_, y_] := term11[x, y] + term22*term33[x, y];

term44[x_, y_] := γ1/2. + DD[x, y]/(Abs[(Abs[Ωmw])^2 - (detuningP + detuning1 + I γ2/2.) (detuningP + detuning2 +  I γ3/2.)])^2;

Susceptibility[x_, y_] := term44[x, y]/(Abs[detuningP + I γ1/2. + termA[x, y]])^2;

ProbeAbsorption[x_, y_] := Im[ComplexExpand[Susceptibility[x, y]/k]];

data = Table[ProbeAbsorption[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

This, however returns a list of zeros:

```
Select[data, # != 0 &]

(*    {}  *)
```

Comment: Many thanks to you @Alexei for making the corrections in the code. As I am new in Mathematica your corrections meant a lot to me.
After implementing your corrections to the code, I'm not able to see the expressions in the form of x and y. For ex. if I want to check the expression of term44 after the evaluation in terms of x and y, what to do?

Comment: @Pacifier you should take this function defined such as I did it above and simply put the values instead of x and y. For example, `term44[3,3]`. If it does not return a numerical value you may try `term44[3,3]//N`

Comment: It solved the problem. Thanx